# Focusing Area in Android Camera ignores the area specified

Tags: android, android-camera

This is the code I have implemented where I want to focus the specific spot I have defined from rectangle. The rectangle comes from another class called SelectedView which draws a rectangle of my desired shape. The problem I am getting is, the focus I have implemented for the project completely ignores the spot and performs a normal overall focus instead of the rect area which I have specified from selectedView.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mOriginalCamera.getParameters();

List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();

if(focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO ))
                   {
                       parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO );
                   }

if(focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)){

                       parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                   }
                   else if(focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)){
                       parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                   }



                   if(parameters.isZoomSupported())
                   {
                       int maxZoom = parameters.getMaxZoom();
                       Log.e(" Max zoom ", String.valueOf(maxZoom));
                       if(maxZoom > 5)
                       {
                           parameters.setZoom(5);
                       }
                   }

                   if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                   {
                       {
                           parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
                           parameters.set("rotation",90);
                       }
                   }



                   int maxFocusArea= parameters.getMaxNumFocusAreas();
                   if(maxFocusArea!=0)
                   {
                       Rect focusArea = new Rect();
                       focusArea = SelectedView.focusRect;

                       List<Camera.Area> focusList = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
                       Camera.Area cameraArea = new Camera.Area(focusArea, 1000);
                       focusList.add(cameraArea);

                       parameters.setFocusAreas(focusList);
                       parameters.setMeteringAreas(focusList);
                   }

                   mOriginalCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                   mOriginalCamera.setParameters(parameters);

                   mOriginalCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
                       @Override
                       public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {

                       }
                   });
```

The selectedView class has static rect and I get that value from onDraw method as :

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        int height = RechargeActivity.oldSurfaceView.getHeight();

        canvas.drawRect(40,height/2-40,(int)getScreenWidth()-40,height/2,paint);
        focusRect = new Rect(40,40,(int)getScreenWidth()-40,100);
    }
```

Comment: How do you know this is not working? Note that your rectangle is probably wrong. Camera.Area *coordinates are mapped so that (-1000, -1000) is always the top-left corner of the current field of view, and (1000, 1000) is always the bottom-right corner of the current field of view*

Comment: The screen focuses on whole surfaceView, but I only want the screen to focus on the reectangle